# Hyperledger Fabric Playground Issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have, installed hyperledger fabric using per-requisits and also installed hyerpledger composer playground on local. I have also created PeerAdminCard on one of the Dev server hlfv11. I have created empty business network through playground and deployed it. When I try to connect to network the "Connect Now" button is disabled.

Can anyone please help what could be the issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8QEf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once you create peer card, you need to create business network and install business network on that card.
yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork

1. Enter test-network as network name and desired information for description, author name, and author email
2. Select Apache-2.0 as the license
3. Enter org.example.empty
4. Select No when asked whether to generate an empty network

composer archive create -t dir -n .

To install the business network
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile test-network@0.0.1.bna

To start the business network
composer network start --networkName test-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

To import the network administrator identity as a usable business network card
composer card import --file networkadmin.card